# Custom substitution in a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I'm a beginner with Mathematica, hope this is an interesting question.

Basically I would like to write a function that takes a 3-variable polynomial as input and linearly maps it in an another expression based on the degrees of each monomial.

I give you an example.
Suppose I've a function:

```
f[a_,b_,c_] = some expression depending on a,b,c
```

Now I want to define a Mathematica function $g$ such that:

$g(\alpha x^ay^bz^c + \beta x^dy^ez^f) = \alpha f(a,b,c) + \beta f(d,e,f)$

**Some practical example:**

$g(xy+yx+z) = 2f(1,1,0) + f(0,0,1)$

$g(xz^3y^2 + xyxz^2) = f(1,2,3) + f(2,1,2)$

I have no idea how to do such a thing. I was thinking to use the `/.` operator, but I've realised soon that is not the correct instrument since I'm not able to make it work in general.

I appreciate also a reference from where I can extract the answer, if replying is too complicated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like `Total[KeyValueMap[#2 Apply[f, #1] &, Association @ CoefficientRules[x y^2 z^3 + x y x z^2]]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Replace` rather than `ReplaceAll` (aka `/.`), which allows you finer control.  Here's what I came up with:

```
expr = 2 x z^3 y^2 + x y x z^2
Total[Replace[CoefficientRules[expr, {x, y, z}], {Rule -> Times, List -> f}, {2, 3}, Heads -> True]]
```

Step by step:

- `CoefficientRules[expr, {x, y, z}]` returns `{{2, 1, 2} -> 1, {1, 2, 3} -> 2}`, or (if we apply `FullForm`)

  ```
  List[Rule[List[2,1,2],1],Rule[List[1,2,3],2]]
  ```
- If we can replace the innermost `List`s with `f`s and the `Rule`s with multiplication, then we've got what we want.  This is what the `Replace` command does:  replace `{Rule -> Times, List -> f}`, but only at levels `{2,3}`, and allow Mathematica to replace the `Head`s of expressions.  This yields

  ```
  List[f[2,1,2],Times[2,f[1,2,3]]]
  ```
- Finally, `Total` adds up all the elements of this list, yielding

  ```
  2 f[1, 2, 3] + f[2, 1, 2]
  ```

Comment: Best answer I could ever get! It works and there is a detailed explanation of why